# How to convert octet-stream to images

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of files in `.ikc` format:

**File Type**: data MIME;

**Type**: application/octet-stream;

**Suggested file extension(s)**: bin, lha, lzh, exe, class, so, dll, img, & iso.

They should have been `svg` images, supposedly, but I couldn't find an online converter that worked. Is there a way to convert octet-stream to `svg` or `png` images?

Aside from online converters, I tried:

```
(async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/image/png')
  const blob = await res.blob()
  const img = new Image()
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  // newer promise based version of img.onload
  await img.decode()
  
  document.body.append(img)

  // Don't forget to revoke the blob url when 
  // you no longer need it (to release memory)
  URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
})()
```

Nothing happened, but I don't know how to adapt this better to my case.

First few lines of one of my files:

```
J�@^)T����
��;�\�E$��,SwU�KI
�x���j�4�.�V�   �
_�ؑiY�=l����<�M7l�Xq�f�~�x�@ɷ���|>���=UO#$nr����V38GQK��p
```

Used [tomeko.net](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en) to convert the file to hexadecimal

```
0x4A, 0xEB, 0x13, 0x00, 0x40, 0x5E, 0x29, 0x1E, 0x54, 0xF6, 0xF6, 0xC0, 0xC2, 0x0F, 0x0A, 0xFB, 
0x90, 0x3B, 0xDB, 0x5C, 0xB9, 0x45, 0x24, 0x8A, 0xDA, 0x0B, 0x2C, 0x53, 0x77, 0x55, 0xBD, 0x4B, 
0x49, 0x7F, 0x0A, 0xC7, 0x1F, 0x78, 0x96, 0xFD, 0xFA, 0x6A, 0xA5, 0x34, 0x8C, 0x2E, 0x9C, 0x0C, 
0x56, 0x9D, 0x09, 0xB4, 0x0A, 0x5F, 0xE9, 0xD8, 0x91, 0x69, 0x59, 0xBB, 0x3D, 0x6C, 0xB2, 0x80,
```

Does anyone know what to do with this?

Comment: Where did you get these ".ikc" files?: probably a proprietary application format. You can't convert files to other formats on a raw data/encoding level. You'll need a suitable converter. Besides you can't convert pixel based formats like png, jpg etc to vector formats like svg without a tracing/vectorization process.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to fetch the source and convert it yourself, you can use the Image API regularly:

```js
const image = new Image();
image.src = "https://httpbin.org/image/png";

image.decode().then(() => {
  document.body.append(image);
});
```